# Cannot install libgtkmm-2.4-dev in Kubuntu 13.10 - unmet dependencies

Tags: installation, grub2, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to install grub-customizer in Kubuntu 13.10.  After a lot of fiddling, following various online advice, I got to the point where I needed to install libgtkmm-2.4-dev (which I know nothing about).  Here's what I got when I tried:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgtkmm-2.4-dev :
 Depends: libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed

 Depends: libglibmm-2.4-dev (>= 2.27.93) but it is not going to be installed

 Depends: libpangomm-1.4-dev (>= 2.27.1) but it is not going to be installed

 Depends: libatkmm-1.6-dev (>= 2.22.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

And now I can get no further.

Comment: Use [Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) once to install the particular missing packages. Search in **synaptic** in the reverse order from the list you got in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

From `apt-get`'s manpage:

```
   -f, --fix-broken
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
       This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
       to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
       specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
       is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
       system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
       so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
       using dselect(1) or dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the
       offending packages). Use of this option together with -m may
       produce an error in some situations. Configuration Item:
       APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Try `sudo apt-get install -f` then `sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-dev`.

Comment: No joy, alas.  Running those two commands still produces the same error.

Comment: @user101815 How about `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libglibmm-2.4-dev libpangomm-1.4-dev libatkmm-1.6-dev libgtkmm-2.4-dev`?